# Why am i getting the error "Array type Item[1000] is not assignable"?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm quite new to c++, I need a bit of help on this error, 
'Array type Item[1000] is not assignable' ? I'm on XCode by the way,
I know I should be on Windows. This is a school homework, so if you
could guide me, without giving much away, that would be awesome. Oh and sorry
if I mess something up, this is my first post.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//global constant
const int MAX_SIZE = 1000;

//make an Item class
class Item
{
private:
    string id;
    int sold, remain;
public:
    void set_id(string _id);
    void set_sold(int _sold);
    void set_remain(int _remain);

};

//all the methods setting id, sold, and remaining
void Item::set_id(string _id){
    id = _id;
}
void Item::set_sold(int _sold){
    sold = _sold;
}
void Item::set_remain(int _remain){
    remain = _remain;
}

//code to read from file
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

//function that reads file to array
void read_In()  **I think it's because this should not be a void**
{ 

    //variables
    int ct = MAX_SIZE;
    Item a[MAX_SIZE];

    //open the file
    inFile.open( "inventory.txt" );

    //while the file hasn't ended, read and place into array of Items
    while( !inFile.eof() ){

        string for_id = "";
        int for_sold = 0;
        int for_remain = 0;

        for(int i = 0;i<ct;i++){

            //store the next thing on the file to the array of Items
            inFile >> for_id;
            a[i].set_id(for_id);
            inFile >> for_sold;
            a[i].set_sold(for_sold);
            inFile >> for_remain;
            a[i].set_remain(for_remain);

        }

    }
    inFile.close();
}

int main(){

    Item sp[MAX_SIZE];
    sp = read_In();  **Apparently the error is here!**

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That error also mentioned which line of code caused the error.  Where is the error?

Comment: `read_In` doesn't return anything, so you can't assign it's (non-existent) return value to a variable.

Comment: First `read_In` returns `void` meaning it returns _nothing_. Second you can't assign arrays to arrays, it's just not part of the language. Use `std::array` for a fixed sized array or `std::vector` if you need a variable sized array. If you _must_ used naked arrays check out [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: The error is pretty clear: Arrays aren't assignable. Also, your `read_In()` function doesn't return anything but your're assigning it to something anyway? You should take the array and size as a parameter instead.

Comment: on a side note there is nothing wrong with writing C++ on OSX, in XCode or otherwise

Answer (score 2):

First of all close comments properly. Half of errors will be go. Secondly, you are using,

```
void read_In(){
```

So read_In returns void.. then you cannot take it's value, `sp = read_In();` is wrong.

Comment: So, if I change read_In to, let's say to Item read_in and return an Item, then assign sp = read_In, will this work, or is this considered illegal?

Comment: `sp` is array, you will return single element form read_In, right? So in that case you need to use index like, `sp[index]=read_In();`